# downloaded 114 from 109 chrome webdriver but still taking 109

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have previously used the same path and it was working with other projects. However, this new project is not executing and is showing the error below. I have downloaded ChromeDriver version 114 and ensured that the path is correct, but the issue persists.
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver","C:\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 109
Current browser version is 114.0.5735.134 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Host info: host: 'NIRALI-PC', ip: '192.168.0.11'
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)

Thanks
Looking forward for solutions.

Comment: I found problem. its Capital letters.